# Ayuda con Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Diseñar con código en lenguaje T-SQL un bloque de instrucciones que calcule la media de edad de los empleados, y nos muestre un mensaje por consola indicando si la media supera o no los 50 años de edad.

tabla empleados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me dice como saco la edad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello necesitas apoyarte en una función llamada **DATEDIFF**, la cuál recibe 3 parámetros, edad inicial, edad final y el dato que necesites (año, día, mes, etc).

```
SELECT *, --  Las columnas de tu tabla
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, BirthDate, GETDATE())  --  El cálculo
FROM TABLA
```

Comment: y el resto del ejercicio

Comment: Tu pregunta fue "¿Como saco la edad?".